# MS Access context menu filter message The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'me'

Tags: ms-access, office-automation

I have a form that I open in either datasheet or continuous forms view with four fields bound to text columns in a linked table. If I right click for the context menu and filter on column 1 or 2 equal to one of the values it filters OK; If I try to filter on field 3 or 4 I get the message "The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'me'". If I select 'Text Filter' on fields 3 or 4 and enter some text, it filters OK.

I would be grateful if anybody that has experienced this can tell me why it happens and how to either trap or stop it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any VBA code associated with the form?

Comment: Yes, there is code in the Form_Load

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Conditional Formatting on the columns. If I remove conditional formatting, filtering via the context menu works fine, replace the formatting and filtering shows the message (but still filters correctly!!)

Comment: If this is your own answer to your question please mark the question as answered. In addition you could use the `displayalerts` property before you filter to hide the message and reactivate it immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but you are correct.  I also discovered the cause of this error was incorrect Conditional Formatting.  I kept getting an error on a form about "Object doesn't contain the Automation object [text box]".  I couldn't find that [text box] anywhere.  Then I realized I had Conditional Formatting on some of the fields.  Sure enough, one of the Conditional Formatting rules was referencing this text box that apparently I had removed.