# Ghosts of dead MS Access Controls

Tags: ms-access

I have a very strange bug in a front-end Access form that I cannot figure out.

I have a Main form with a subform datasheet and several controls. When a user tried to use the subform's built in filters, they *sometimes* get a

"This object does not contain the automation object 'cboRefinementOrderCode'"

It is very hard to troubleshoot because sometimes you get the error message and other times, doing the exact same thing, same filter, same column, no error message.

The object in the error message 'cboRefinementOrderCode' is an old combo box control that used to be on the Main form - it was deleted long ago. I have searched the VBA for this object with no references to it. I've even decomposed the whole project into text files and searched the text for the control name and turned up nothing. I've decompiled/recompiled code, compacted and repaired the DB, Imported all forms into a fresh new Access project... All of this and I still can't seem to get rid of this message. Additionally, there is no event vba for OnFilter. So, I just can't understand what VBA it is trying to run when a user filters the subform and why it only sometimes errors. I'm desperate for other ideas.

Comment: Have you seen question? It sugests toggling displayalerts while filtering. Can't say i love the answer, but it might be worth a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519797/ms-access-context-menu-filter-message-the-object-doesnt-contain-the-automation

Comment: That's interesting. I think it may have something to do with conditional formatting. I'll keep investigating along these lines... as baffling as it is. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is super weird but I guess I found an acceptable workaround. My guess is that the subform is corrupt but it would be such a massive pain to try and rebuild the thing from scratch that it is not worth the work (especially if it doesn't end up fixing it).

I isolated the issue to the subform's On-Current event, which triggers right after the filter finishes. In my case, the On-Current event will fire off an exit sub command at the start if a check box on the form is ticked. I discovered that the error was only happening when this box was ticked and code was being skipped in the On_Current. For some reason, it will throw this error only when entering the on_current and doing nothing. I just added a code snipit to change the caption of a button to itself just to give it something to do to the form. The error went away.